# How to register a javascript block from code behind using RegisterClientScriptBlock in Asp.net web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a user control `TreeView` in `aspx` and trying to add a functionality in my asp.net app to select the node(customer name) and update name using `updateName` function based on the selected(node)customer name. I tried it to register javascript at the Page-level in my Page_Load by calling `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` and passing it the script I want but it does not hit that script. Please help.

Comment: Try to do it like this: `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), null, "updateName('" + selectedName + "');", true);`

Comment: @jamshaid kamran Tried it but still does not hit JS code. Please help.

Comment: Check for Console errors, Or directly call the line of code you are hitting: `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), null, string.Format("document.getElementById('CustName').innerHTML = '{0}'", selectedName ), true);`

Comment: Yes, maybe because when it is posting back it has not loaded the js files you got. Try including the method in your markup page and possible wrap it around `<script></script>` tags without declaring it in `document.ready` or in `window.load`

Comment: You will have to understand the issue on your own. I have pointed you out some solutions but I cannot debug into your system to see what is happening and what not.

Comment: You will have to understand the issue on your own. I have pointed you out some solutions but I cannot debug into your system to see what is happening and what not.

Comment: Try to include your `.js` file before you call the method. Declare a literal control in aspx and set its text to the `script` reference of your `js` file. then after that call your method. See what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your help.